# my array elements have the same id in Java?

Tags: java, jquery, arrays

this is basically a program to multiply two Sparse matrix. I have an array of type SpEntry (a class with 3 instant variables, int row,column,value & getter & setter methods), when I wanna set the elements of the arrays created for my objects (m_1 & m_2 are instances of class SpArray & for each theren is a SpEntry[] spArray of size of their non-zero elemts)
when i wanna set the elements of each array,i fond out that m_1[0], & m_1[1] (the elements of m_1 array)  have the same id, thus when i'm setting m_1[0]'s row,col,val the elements are duplicated for m_1[1]'s row,col,val as well

```
public class SpArray {
    public static int N ; //size of NxN matrix
    private SpEntry[] spArray;

    public SpArray(int nNZ){
        spArray = new SpEntry[nNZ];  //nNZ is the number of Non-Zero elements of the sparse matrix

        SpEntry init = new SpEntry(0,0,0);
        for (int s=0; s<spArray.length ; s++){
            spArray[s]= init ; 

        }

    }




    //returns the spArray
    public SpEntry[] getSpArray (){
        return this.spArray;
    }




    //returns the spArray elements
        public SpEntry getSpArray (int index){
            return this.spArray[index];
        }
```

that was a part of the SpArray class
& in the main program:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nnz_1;
    int nnz_2;
    SpArray m_1;
    SpArray m_2;


    input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the size of your square sparse matrix: ");
    SpArray.N = input.nextInt();

    //getting the non zero elements of the 1st sparse matrix & making its sparse array
```

System.out.println("Please enter the number of non-zero elements in the first sparse matrix:   ");
        nnz_1 = input.nextInt();

```
    m_1 = new SpArray (nnz_1);

    for(int j_1=0; j_1<nnz_1 ; j_1++){
    System.out.println("Enter number "+ (j_1+1) + " non-zero element of the 1st sparse matrix");
        System.out.println("row: ");
        int r_1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("column: ");
        int c_1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Value: ");
        int v_1 = input.nextInt();


        /*
        SpEntry e_1 = new SpEntry (r_1, c_1, v_1);
        m_1.getSpArray()[j_1].setRow(e_1.getRow());
        m_1.getSpArray()[j_1].setCol(e_1.getCol());
        m_1.getSpArray()[j_1].setVal(e_1.getVal());
        */

        //new versiin revised
        SpEntry e_1 = new SpEntry (r_1, c_1, v_1);
        m_1.getSpArray(j_1).setRow(e_1.getRow());
        m_1.getSpArray(j_1).setCol(e_1.getCol());
        m_1.getSpArray(j_1).setVal(e_1.getVal());**

    }
```

when I debug the program it shows that the elements of array of m_1 have the same id  (and the same strory for m_2) :

```
m_1           Value: SpArray (id=21)`enter code here`
  spArray            SpEntry[2] (id=22)
    [0]              SpEntry   (id=661)
    [1]              SpEntry   (id=661)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
public SpArray(int nNZ){
    spArray = new SpEntry[nNZ];  //nNZ is the number of Non-Zero elements of the sparse matrix

    SpEntry init = new SpEntry(0,0,0);       // Problem here
    for (int s=0; s<spArray.length ; s++){
        spArray[s]= init ; 

    }

}
```

You create only one object, and you populate the whole matrx with the same object.

If you want the objects to be distinct, you need to create a new object for each element:

```
public SpArray(int nNZ){
    spArray = new SpEntry[nNZ];  //nNZ is the number of Non-Zero elements of the sparse matrix

    for (int s=0; s<spArray.length ; s++){
        spArray[s]= new SpEntry(0,0,0) ; 

    }

}
```